# Earthquake Richter scale problem: Calculate the difference of intensity

Tags: algebra-precalculus, measure-theory, logarithms, education

This is my first time posting here, or in any math forum, and I really need help.

I was working on an assignment on compounded interest and out of nowhere I see this problem about the Richter scale, which I have no idea how to solve.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rn7D3.png)

My best guesss has been to try to replace the *R* by the values mentioned in the problem and then change the log to exponential form, but I still don't have the answer and I am pretty sure that what I got is completely wrong.

This is my development of the problem, just in case.

$3=log(\dfrac{I}{I0}) \Rightarrow 10^3= \dfrac{I}{I0} \Rightarrow 1000\times I0=I $

$8.25=log(\dfrac{I}{I0}) \Rightarrow 10^8.25=\dfrac{I}{I0} \Rightarrow 10^8.25\times I0=I$

$(10^{8.25} \times I0=I)$  / $(10^{8.25} \times I0=I) $

Please, Could you help me with this? I would very much appreciate it.

Comment: Please see the **Edit-Images** section in [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).

Answer (score 1):

From the definition,

$(10^R)$ is linearly proportional to $I$.

That is, $~\displaystyle (10^R) = I \times \frac{1}{I_0}.$

Therefore, the ratio of the intensities is

$$\frac{(10)^{(8.25)}}{(10)^{(3)}} = (10)^{(5.25)}.$$